# Rotating 3D Object Towards Swipe Direction

Tags: unity, rotation

I have a character that has a constant speed, and I want to be able to change its direction with swipe gestures,
The exact same mechanism implemented [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeSQwRRIDsc).

I managed to do that for movement only, without taking into account the rotation, but I want to create  this mechanism in such way that the rigidbody will have constant force in the `transform.forward` direction, and the Y rotation will change according to the swipe gestures, so the character will always move forward in local space, but will face towards different direction according to the assigned rotation.

I couldn't find a proper way of finding the desired rotation by the swipe direction.

How can I achieve this logic?

Comment: Maybe, you could try making a variable and adding the [change in touch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-deltaPosition.html) to it. Then you can take the x of the Vector2 and rotating the player based on that. A more detailed explanation will be provided if you request it.

Comment: I actually did something similar but I need the character to be rotated by both x and y Touch.deltaPosition. That's make it harder to implement, unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using `Quaternion.LookRotation()` -
I used it to translate the swipe gesture to a Vector3 that is representing the direction.
I used this code inside the `Update()` method to retrieve the user's input:

```
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                currDirectionX = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;
                currDirectionZ = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y;
            }
            moveDirection = new Vector3(currDirectionX, 0f, currDirectionZ).normalized;
```

and this code inside the `FixedUpdate()` method to rotate towards the desired rotation, while constantly moving forward in local space:

```
    Quaternion targetRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(this.transform.rotation, targetRot, 8f);
    rb.AddForce((speed * transform.forward) - rb.velocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted if it worked for you.